SharePoint online library column JSON formatting based on other column value
I need to format a column named 'Action' with hyperlink as follows:

If column name 'Status' is having value as "Accepted" or "Rejected" then 'Action' column should have hyperlink as 'View' and on click of it it should open view form.
Else if column name 'Status' is having any other value, then 'Action' column should have hyperlink as 'Edit' and on click of it it should open edit form.

Any help will be appreciated.

Just wanted to confirm if you are using a "list" or "document library"? Generally libraries only have a "Properties" form.

Thank you @GaneshSanap-MVP for your reply.
I'm using Document Library. This Status is custom column which shows current Status of that item.
Basically, I want to provide Edit functionality for In-Progress items & if item's status is Accepted/Rejected, then users can only View them with this link. I'm using List Based PowerApps Form to edit/view item details. PowerApps form is working fine. Now using JSON formatting I want to customize this Action column & redirect based on Status.
Thanks,
Sanjay

Check my answer below and let me know if it helps.

The button seems to do this, please refer:
https://michelcarlo.com/2022/05/19/sharepoint-custom-view-and-edit-buttons-using-list-formatting/

You can try using SharePoint JSON column formatting like below for your Action column to open the forms based on "Status":
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Status]=='Accepted' || [$Status]=='Rejected', 'View', 'Edit') + ' Form'",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=@currentWeb + '/Shared Documents/Forms/' + if([$Status]=='Accepted' || [$Status]=='Rejected', 'dispform', 'editform') + '.aspx?ID=' + [$ID]",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}

Where:

[$Status] is an internal name of your column in SharePoint list in this format: [$InternalNameOfColumn]. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?
Shared Documents is the name of document library you can find from library URL: Check SharePoint Online List/Library URL Name.

Output:


Additional:
You can try using SharePoint JSON column formatting like below for your Action column to open the "Properties" form for all conditions:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Open Form",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "editProps"
  }
}

Output:

